# More info about your jQuery.youtubin post to overcome IE security warning

Tags: jquery

We've used the youtubin for jquery on our page and we still get the security warning in IE. Did you do more than simply use the script?

Answer (score 0):

You also need [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to overcome the security warning in IE. youtubin will automatically use swfobject, if it's available. You can easily test it by just linking the Google hosted swfobject.js.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your included css and js files are either relative references or fully qualified urls with https in front.  Including the swfobject.js from google code should also be referenced with https.